# Solving PDE like ODE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is it possible to treat
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}g(\tau,s)+g(\tau,s)=e^s e^{3\tau}$$
like an ODE and solve for $g(\tau,s)$? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, consider $s$ as a "parameter" and solve the linear ODE with respect to $\tau$:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \tau}+g=e^s e^{3\tau}\implies g(\tau,s)=\underbrace{C(s)e^{-\tau}}_{\text{hom. sol.}}+\underbrace{\frac{e^se^{3\tau}}{4}}_{\text{part. sol.}}.$$
where $C(s)$ is a function in $s$.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. But a problem occurs to me. What if the equation takes the form $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}g(\tau,s)+g(\tau,s)=e^{3\tau s}?$$ Is there anything we can do?

Comment: You can do the same, but for the particular solution you should pay attention to the case when $3s=-1$.

Comment: Could you say more, please?

Comment: Have you tried to solve it when $3s=-1$?

Comment: Why does $3s$ need to equal $-1$?

Comment: Please try to solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}g(\tau,s)+g(\tau,s)=e^{3\tau s}$ using the same approach and show your attempt under your question.